# Use `chromatic-sass` in a Vue project (or make any JavaScript functions available in Sass files/blocks)

Tags: vue.js, sass, node-sass, vue-cli-3

I want to use [`chromatic-sass`](https://github.com/bugsnag/chromatic-sass) in a Vue application generated by the Vue CLI 3 ([`@vue/cli`](https://cli.vuejs.org/)).

However, `chromatic-sass` isn't written in SASS, so I can't `@import` it from a `.scss` file or `<style lang="scss">` block. Because it's written in JavaScript (CoffeeScript to be exact), it needs to be bridged by configuring the SASS renderer.

Here's [how the docs recommend integrating it](https://github.com/bugsnag/chromatic-sass) into a project:

```js
var sass = require("node-sass");
var chromatic = require("chromatic-sass");

sass.render({
  file: scss_filename,
  functions: chromatic
}, function(err, result) { /*...*/ });
```

The problem is, when using the Vue CLI, I don't have access to or control over how `node-sass` is used.

What's the easiest way I can get `chromatic-sass` working in a project generated by the Vue CLI? Is this possible via a config file modification?

---

I'm hoping for a complete answer (working code) rather than pointing me in a direction. The solution shouldn't otherwise modify how Vue handles SCSS files.

If it matters, the Vue CLI settings I used:

```
Vue CLI v3.3.0
? Please pick a preset: Manually select features
? Check the features needed for your project: Babel, CSS Pre-processors
? Pick a CSS pre-processor (PostCSS, Autoprefixer and CSS Modules are supported by default): Sass/SCSS
? Where do you prefer placing config for Babel, PostCSS, ESLint, etc.?: In dedicated config files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just pass needed options to SASS preprocessor.

**`vue.config.js`**:

```js
const chromatic = require('chromatic-sass');

module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        functions: chromatic
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I've tested it on newly created project using your settings and it works as expected.

Documentation: [Vue CLI 3 → Passing Options to Pre-Processor Loaders](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders)

Comment: I am most grateful. I suspected the solution was straightforward, but for some reason config files are completely intractable to me. Many thanks.